# Word for the act one does with one's hand when shooing someone/something

Tags: single-word-requests, verbs

Often, when someone yells "shoo", or "get out of here", it is often accompanied by a hand gesture. It looks kind of like a brush through the air, only more aggressive, and sometimes it kind of looks like they're pointing them away.

Comment: This _could_ be a duplicate of [Is the verb for this gesture 'wave off'?'](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/510785/is-the-verb-for-this-gesture-wave-off/510804#510804) The alternative verb + object is '_wave someone away_'

Comment: The gesture is not universal; there are others. But @Edwin's  right about the idiomatic verb phrase. _Wave s.o. off_ is another synonym. Both are phrasal verbs and take Particle Shift.

Comment: "Flick" might fit, when you wave with the back of the hand.

Comment: You can [shoo](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/shoo) someone or something away with your hands or arms.

Comment: non-verbal gestures are often interpreted differently  given  cultural context. Provided  I am understanding  the Q correctly, in Latin American it is the "come hither" gesture. Quite the opposite of "shoo away".

Comment: @EdwinAshworth What I'm thinking of is more hostile, and the hand/arm is being waved in the horizontal direction. Reminiscient of "flicking", as Hot Licks said in his comment (could be the correct word as well, though I don't think so).

Comment: @Anton, see comment made for Edwin.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey I see, so it could be used in such a manner: "You're free. F*ck off," Damian said, shooing him with his hand.